# Capture output of piped command while still knowing if first command wrote to stderr

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to capture the output of `cmd2` from `cmd1 | cmd2` while still knowing if `cmd1` wrote to `stderr`?

I am using [`exiftool`](https://exiftool.org/) to strip exif data from files:

```
exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o -
```

This writes the output to `stdout`. This works for most files. If the file is corrupt or not a video/image file it will not write anything to `stdout` and, instead, write an error to `stderr`. For example:

```
Error: Writing of this type of file is not supported - /path/to/file.ext
```

I ultimately need to capture the md5 of files that don't result in an error. Right now I am doing this:

```
md5=$(exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
```

Regardless if the file is a image/video, it'll calculate an md5.

If the file is an image/video, it'll capture the file's md5 as expected.

If the file is **not** an image/video, `exiftool` doesn't write anything to `stdout` and so `md5sum` calculates the md5 of the null input. But that line will also write an error to `stderr`.

I need to be able to check if something was written to `stderr` so I know to scrap the calculated md5.

I know one alternative is to run the `exiftool` twice: one time without the `md5sum` and without capturing to see if anything was written to `stderr` and then a second time with the `md5sum` and capturing. But this means I have to run `exiftool` twice. I want to avoid that because it can take a long time for big files. I'd rather only run it once.

**Update**

Also, I can't capture the output of just `exiftool` because it yields this error:

```
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

And I cannot ignore this error because the md5 result is not the same. That is to say:

```
file=$(exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o -)
echo "$file" | md5sum
```

Will print the above null byte error and will not have the same md5 result as:

```
exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - | md5sum
```

Comment: Can you save `exitftool` output in a variable, check `$?`, and then pipe it if `$?=0`?

Comment: you may cut in stages `exif_output=$(exiftool ..); [[ -n $exif_output ]] || <return/break/exit>; md5=$(md5sum <<<"$exif_output")`, there could be an issue if output doesn't have the final newline character because `<<<` would add one, in that case `md5=$(printf "%s" "$exif_output" | md5sum)`

Comment: I updated the question with why I cannot capture the output of just `exiftool`.

Comment: So just toss `$(...)` and save it all to a file. `exiftool ... >out.txt 2>err.txt`. Then just have the control over each file.

Comment: I’m going through 500k files — mostly big ones. Writing to disk will be very taxing and slow.

Comment: The *warning* about an ignored NUL byte is just that -- it's a *warning*, not an error.

Comment: And you can capture such data faithfully if you capture it into an array. `readarray -d '' array_name < <(...command that can emit NUL bytes...)`

Comment: then the content up to the first NUL will be in `${array_name[0]}`, the content between the first NUL and the second will be in `${array_name[1]}`, etc.

Comment: Just because you do `cmd > file` doesn't mean the OS is going to waste time actually writing to disk.  When you do `cmd > file; cmd 2 < file; rm file`, any reasonable modern OS will keep the data completely in cache and it will never waste time on a physical disk write.   If you're really concerned about it, use a ram disk.

Comment: Also, *in general*, you shouldn't assume that any write to stderr == something went wrong. POSIX specifies stderr to be used for *all* diagnostic logging. That means prompts, it means informational logging, it means any manner of things that *aren't actually errors*.

Comment: @WilliamPursell, ...that's not necessarily true -- depends very much on mount flags. Tuning for persistence over performance isn't necessarily bad policy, either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Valid point.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can't ignore the NUL byte warning since it alters the MD5 result. Would calculating the md5 `array_name` yield the expected result? Meaning it would equal `exiftool ... | md5sum`? RE: `stderr == something went wrong` - aware and agree; however, for my specific use case, it is an error.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan, if you capture into an array (+ a regular string with any content after the last NUL), you can use the array again to reproduce the output to feed into md5sum, with `printf '%s\0' "${array[@]}"; printf '%s' "$tail"`. Only caveat is that you need to track whether there was a terminal NUL on the output, but that's doable.

Comment: `{ while IFS= read -r -d '' segment; do array+=( "$segment" ); done; [[ $segment ]] && tail="$segment"; } < <(exiftool ...)` should generate an `array` and a `tail` you can use as described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coprocess can be used for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in [0-3].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4+ required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

coproc STDERR_CHECK { seen=0; while IFS= read -r; do seen=1; done; echo "$seen"; }
{
  md5=$(exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
} 2>&${STDERR_CHECK[1]}
exec {STDERR_CHECK[1]}>&-
read stderr_seen <&"${STDERR_CHECK[0]}"

if (( stderr_seen )); then
  echo "exiftool emitted stdout with md5 $md5, and had content on stderr"
else
  echo "exiftool emitted stdout with md5 $md5, and did not emit any content on stderr"
fi
```

Comment: I need some time to digest this. I am not familiar with co-processes so I need to read up on them.

Comment: *nod*; let me know if you have any specific questions. If you want to have the coprocess look for a specific error message, or return a count of lines seen, or so forth -- it's arbitrary code, so all very doable.

Comment: So, my understanding: create a named (extended) coproc that sets `seen` to 1 when/if any data is send to it > execute the command in a function block and send `stderr` of the function block to the coproc > this would trigger setting the `seen` variable of the coproc if, and only if, the function block actually writes anything to `stderr` > then read data from the coproc which would return `1` if, and only if, the function block actually wrote anything to `stderr`. Just reading up on coprocs -- wicked cool stuff!

Comment: That explanation is spot on.

Comment: So this way works the best in that it does not alter the md5 result like what happens with the other answers. Awesome. Thank you!

Comment: If I wanted to check thousands of files, what would I need to do to 'reset' the coproc? I have a `while` loop that is getting data from a `find` (i.e. `while read line... done < <(find ... )`. In the `while` loop I will need to do the above for every file.

Comment: `wait "$STDERR_CHECK_PID"` will let the process finish exiting and reap its zombie from the table. If you do that *after* you've read its results, my offhand recollection is that that should be all the cleanup needed before a new one can be started under the same name -- but I'm not in a place to verify that personally until tomorrow.

Comment: Honestly, if I needed to write something that was going to be fast when looping over a very large number of files, I'd pick a different implementation language -- say, Go with [`go-exif`](https://github.com/dsoprea/go-exif); or Julia with [`ImageMagick.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaIO/ImageMagick.jl/blob/master/src/ImageMagick.jl). Using *any* program you need to run a separate copy of per file scanned is going to add up to a lot of overhead at-scale.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I'll work on after I get this working cause I'll need to learn a new language for that and I don't have time just yet. I have been meaning to learn Go so this will be a great exercise.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special var(array) for this `PIPESTATUS`, simple example, file and file2 exist

```
$ ls file &> /dev/null | ls file2 &> /dev/null; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 0
```

And here file3 not exist

```
$ ls file3 &> /dev/null | ls file2 &> /dev/null; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
2 0

$ ls file3; echo $?
ls: cannot access 'file3': No such file or directory
2
```

Triple pipe

```
$ ls file 2> /dev/null | ls file3 &> /dev/null | ls file2 &> /dev/null; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0 2 0
```

Pipe in var tested with `grep`

```
$ test=$(ls file | grep .; ((${PIPESTATUS[1]} > 0)) && echo error)
$ echo $test
file

$ test=$(ls file3 | grep .; ((${PIPESTATUS[1]} > 0)) && echo error)
ls: cannot access 'file3': No such file or directory
$ echo $test
error
```

Another approach is to check that file type is image or video first.

```
type=$(file "/path/to/file.ext")
case $type in
    *image*|*Media*) echo "is an image or video";;
esac
```

Comment: Unfortunately `exiftool` does not always return a non zero, even if there is an error/warning. If there is an error, it'll write to `stderr` and return `1`. If there is a warning it'll write to `stderr` but return `0`. I need to know if anything was written to `stderr` even if `exiftool` exits successfully (`0`).

Comment: Then add `grep` as vdavid suggested. The final command would be `exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - | grep . | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}` Grep will ended with error if not matched.

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` doesn't seem to be set when capturing the output. I need to calculate the `md5sum` and, if there was an error, I'll scrap it.

Comment: It's set in subshell, updated the answer with such example.

Comment: This sorta works except that `grep .` alters the md5 calculation for valid files. In other words, the md5 from `exiftool file -all= -o - | md5sum` is different than `exiftool file -all= -o - | grep . | md5sum`.

Comment: In this case i'd check is this file an image or video before run exiftool.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing but its very slow because exiftool takes a long time for big files. So if I have 500k files it'll take O2. Now, after combining the logic, It runs in O.

Comment: Filetype can be checked with `file`.

Comment: That gives me inconsistent results. I have many JPGs that `file` does not yield as image. I will share more details when I get home.

Answer (score 2):

`md5=$(exec 3>&1; (exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - 2>&1 1>&3) 3> >(md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >&3) | grep -q .)`

This opens file descriptor 3 and redirects it to file descriptor 1 (a.k.a. stdout).

The trick is to redirect `exiftool` outputs:

- `exiftool ... 2>&1` tells that file descriptor 2 (a.k.a. stderr) is redirected to stdout
- `exiftool ... 1>&3` tells that stdout is redirected to file descriptor 3 which, at this moment, is redirected to stdout

Then fd 3 is redirected to another chain of commands using process substitution, i.e. `3> >(md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >&3)` where `3>` tells to redirect fd3 and `>(...)` is the process substitution itself.

At the same time, the standard error of `exiftool` is written to the standard output which is piped into `grep -q .` which will return 0 if there is at least one character.

Because `grep -q .` is the last command executed in the main chain of commands, you can simply check the results of `$?`:

```sh
md5=$(exec 3>&1; (exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - 2>&1 1>&3) 3> >(md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >&3) | grep -q .)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  # something was written to exiftool's stderr
fi
```

The error will not be written. If you want to see the error but not capture it in `md5` then replace `grep -q .` by `grep . >&2`

`md5=$(exec 3>&1; (exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - 2>&1 1>&3) 3> >(md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >&3) | grep . >&2)`

It is very important that you redirect `exiftool` outputs in this very order. If you redirected like this:

`exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - 1>&3 2>&1`

Then stdout is redirected to fd3 and then stderr is redirected to stdout. But because `1>&3` occurs *before* `2>&1` then stderr will be redirected to stdout which is redirected to fd3 at this time. You definitely don’t want that.

The end of the process substitution chain writes to fd3 with `>&3` because you want to keep the result to fd3. Without `>&3`, the result of `awk` would end up in fd1 which would be piped to `grep -q .` or `grep . >&2` and, again, you definitely don’t want that.

PS. you don’t need to close fd3 because it was opened during a subprocess when assigning `md5`. Should you need to close the file descriptor, please call `exec 3>&-`

Comment: At a cursory glance this seems to work. I will step through it more closely tonight.

Comment: I am still looking into why but for some reason this modifies the md5 calculation. In other words, this does not yield the same md5 value as if I did `exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - | md5sum`.

Comment: That’s weird. I get the same results, but I’m not testing with exiftool, though there’s no reason for exiftool to behave differently when piped and when redirected to a process substitution.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Please try with this slightly simpler version `md5=$(exec 3>&1; (exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - 2>&1 1> >(md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >&3)) | grep . >&2)` the difference is that fd3 is used only as the final output, it’s not used as an intermediate fd.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan You could also redirect your output by changing the `-o` option from `-` to the process substitution, e.g. `md5=$(exec 3>&1; (exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o >(md5sum | awk '{print $1}' >&3) 2>&1) | grep . >&2)`

Answer (score 0):

Just capture the output, and then conditionally write it.  eg:

```
if out="$(exiftool "/path/to/file.ext" -all= -o - )"; then
    md5=$(echo "$out" | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'))
fi
```

This makes the assignment to `md5` and returns the exit status of `exiftool`, which is checked by the `if`.  Note that this construction assumes that `exiftool` returns a reasonable exit value.

Comment: The first line will spit a "null byte" error. I can't ignore that error because it alters the md5 result. I updated the question with what I mean.

Comment: BTW, another way to record the output of exiftool avoiding the NUL-byte error is to pipe through `base64`, and `base64 -d` when you need to get it back out. Extra overhead, of course, but sometimes it's a useful approach.